# Doctrine DQL with interface

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity in one of my portable bundles with MappedSuperClass set. I extend it to the real entity for each separate project / website and implement the additional properties in a main project bundle. I'm using the interface and the ResolveTargetEntities to relate the entities using the interfaces. This part works flawlessly so far.

The problem comes with my DQL queries, which need to address that particular implemented entity class, the one that extends the mapped superclass. If I use the interface or the mapped superclass, I get the Symfony errors. But I don't want to use my implementation of the superclass name because that would mean I have to change my portable bundle's repository code for each project, which is unacceptable.

One of the ideas was to get the orm mappings from config in the repository and inject the correct class there. But I can't find the way to extract that info from the config file.

The other, better, one was to create some sort of a listener, which would replace the interface with the real thing for me.

So my questions: Does anyone know if this is the usual behavior for the DQL not to be resolved? Does anyone have any ideas how I would implement the code to achieve the resolution by myself?

Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your concrete class set as a parameter that you are accessing later in your parent bundle. If so you can create a repository for that class (half copied from Sylius).

```
parameters:
    acme.repository.something.class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    // Or your custom repository

services:
    acme.manager.something:
        alias: doctrine.orm.entity_manager

    acme.metadata.something:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata
        factory_service: acme.manager.something
        factory_method: getClassMetadata
        arguments:
            - %acme.model.something.class%

    acme.repository.something:
        class: %acme.repository.something.class%
        arguments:
            - @acme.manager.something
            - @acme.metadata.something
```

Then you can just call the repository using `$this->container->get('acme.repository.something`)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not that I can't access my repository, I'm already doing what you are proposing. The problem is, I'm having a DQL query which gets the data from another entity, not the one the Repository is referencing. So in my DQL I have something like: `SELECT gl, g, c, cl, m, ml FROM Path\Which\Should\Be\an\Interface gl`. The Interface should then be mapped to the correct entity. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Andrej, I had a similiar situation. You can make a setter method in your custom repository that sets the class name to be used in the dql. You can then have that setter method called with the call tag in your service declaration.

This is what I did in my post repo service declaration. I hope it helps. Good luck.

```
    <service id="cfs_blog.post_repository" 
        class="%cfs_blog.post_repository.class%"
        factory-service="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        factory-method="getRepository">
        <argument>%cfs_blog.post.class%</argument>
        <call method="setUserEntityClass">
            <argument>%user_class%</argument>
        </call>
    </service>
```